What steps should I take to ensure my Nest.js app deployed on AWS Fargate displays properly on the Public IP without specifying the port number?
So I have deployed a Nest.js app to AWS Fargate. The thing is when I access the Public IP X.XXX.XXX.XXX the site does not open. But when I type X.XXX.XXX.XXX:3000 the page displays the Hello World! message. Now how can I make the app display it on X.XXX.XXX.XXX?
I have changed the port number of the app to 80 in the main.ts then i opened the command prompt with administrative privileges and typed npm start. The "Hello World!" message displayed. So my question is that do I need to then, modify the inbound rules of the security group of my Fargate Task to allow traffic on port 80 from the desired sources?

When you access the public IP with http:// the browser uses the default HTTP port, which is port 80. When you access it via https:// the browser uses the default HTTPS port, which is port 443. So if you want to access your application directly, you should expose it over the default HTTP or HTTPS port, instead of port 3000.
Note that you really need a load balancer in front of an ECS/Fargate application, as I mentioned in my answer to your other question. A load balancer can handle mapping those default HTTP/HTTPS ports to your application's port 3000.
